# unittest mocks not being torn down correctly

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am using `unittest.mock.patch.object` as a context manager. My understanding was that after hitting the `__exit__` of that context manager nothing would be mocked anymore, but I am pretty sure I'm seeing side-effects of this in other tests. I am using `pytest` as my test framework.

A minimal example looks like:

```py
# my_code.py

from some_other_file import Foo


def main():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.do_something()
```

my aim is to make it so that when `Foo` is instantiated in `my_code.py` it will return a mock, which will be stored in `foo`.

The test looks like:

```py
# test_my_code.py
from unittest import mock

import my_code


def test_main():
    mock_instance = mock.MagicMock()
    with mock.patch.object(my_code.Foo, '__new__', return_value=mock_instance) as foo_constructor:
        my_code.main()
    assert foo_constructor.call_count == 1
    assert mock_instance.do_something.call_count == 1
```

This test passes. The issue is that now all of my other tests which create instances of `Foo` are failing! None of these tests were failing prior to me adding `test_my_code.py`, and when I remove `test_my_code.py` all of those other tests start passing again. What is more, I am using `pytest-random-order` (a plugin which makes `pytest` run its tests in a random order). I have noticed that if `test_main` is the last test to run, everything passes. If `test_main` is the first test to run, it will be the only one which passes. All of the failing tests have tracebacks which end like:

```
variable_in_other_test = Foo()

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

All of these things make me think that the context manager isn't tearing down the mocks when the test is over. I am able to use different mocking approaches (ie those which don't rely on `with mock.patch.object...`) to make my entire test suite work, but really what I am interested in here is understanding why *this* approach fails.

Many thanks.